# Jmeter-How can I extract a value in response header and get count of that

Tags: jmeter

### How to extract a value in response header in jmeter sampler results and get the count.

i am running load test for example say 100 threads. My requests are going to hit 4 servers through load balancer.

I need to get the count of request gone to ABCHeader: Staging 01,Staging 02,Staging 03,Staging 04.(I am getting from response header of each request)

To check whether the requests are getting distributed to each servers evenly. What is the possible way?

I tried with regular expression extractor and extracted the value. But am not sure how to get the count

Please check the response header below: Check for  **ABCHeader: Staging 04**

```
>     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>     Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 17:13:29 GMT
>     Server: Apache
>     Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
>     Vary: Accept-Encoding
>     Expires: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 17:13:29 GMT
>     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
>     Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=fd; expires=Thu, 24-Jan-2019 19:13:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure
>     Set-Cookie: laravelsession=df; expires=Thu, 24-Jan-2019 19:13:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
>     ABCHeader: Staging 04
>     Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>     Connection: Keep-Alive
>     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>     Set-Cookie: abcLB-Staging=df; path=/; Httponly; Secure
>     Content-Length: 2193
>     Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct way is using [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=ABCHeader
   ```

   replace `ABCHeader` with the actual JMeter Variable reference which you defined in the Regular Expression Extractor
2. Next time you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```

   The *result.csv* file will contain an extra column called `ABCHeader` containing the relevant JMeter Variable value so you will be able to distinguish which request is going to which backend server

   [image]
3. Given you are testing the application behind the load balancer make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) to your test plan, otherwise you may run into the situation when all threads are hitting only one backend server.